# Mono Cecil - nullify method / remove method body

Tags: c#, mono, cecil

I am trying to nullify an existing method in a DLL with Mono.Cecil.
By nullify I mean that the method should not do anything.
Simply removing it is not possible, because it is called by other methods.

The method I am trying nullify has the following signature:

`public async Task BulkSendOrganizationInviteEmailAsync(string organizationName, IEnumerable<(OrganizationUser orgUser, ExpiringToken token)> invites, bool isFreeOrg, bool initOrganization = false)`

I have tried various things to achieve this so far:

1. Insert a return instruction as first instruction

   ```
   var returnInst = Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret);
   method.Body.Instructions.Insert(0, returnInst);
   ```

   This did crash the DLL.
2. Insert a return instruction before the first c# method body instruction

   After reading the IL with dotPeek, I could see that the first instructions seem to load the arguments onto the stack, so I moved the return to before the first instruction which was truly part of the C# method body. This again resulted in `Common language runtime detected an invalid program`.
3. Clear instructions / variables

   ```
   method.Body.Instructions.Clear();
   method.Body.Variables.Clear();
   method.Body.InitLocals = true;
   ```

   I have tried various combinations of these 3 commands, but that results in the dll crashing with `Could not load type '<typename>' from assembly '...' because the method 'methodname' has no implementation (no RVA)` when the method is called. When I additionally add a return opcode, it again results in `Common language runtime detected an invalid program`.

I have tried these attempts both with the "real" method and with the nested type method generated presumably due to the async nature (this nested type method contains the actual c# method body), but all of my attempts resulted in the dll crashing.

My question is: How can I nullify the method making the dll crash?